# Error: Asset 'webhooks/ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment' cannot be deployed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I wanted to build a Google assistant with custom actions using actions-sdk. Since I am new to this, I have followed the steps in the tutorial ["Build Actions for Google Assistant using Actions SDK (Level 1)"](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-sdk-1#0) as it is, inorder to build a sample assistant. I followed the tutorial as it is. However, in step 5(Implement fulfillment), when trying to test the the fulfillment  by running the command

```
gactions deploy preview
```

I am getting the below output in the terminal with error

```
Sending configuration files...
Sending resources...
Waiting for server to respond. It could take up to 1 minute if your cloud function needs to be redeployed.
[ERROR] Server did not return HTTP 200.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Asset 'webhooks/ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment' cannot be deployed. [An operation on function cf-_CcGD8lKs_F_LHmFYfJZsQ-name in region us-central1 in project <my-project-id> is already in progress. Please try again later.]"
  }
}
```

And when I checked the "Google Cloud Platform -> Cloud Functions Console" for this project, the following is seen.

Image 1(Screenshot)
[Cloud Platform Cloud Functions Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyGld.png)

A failed deploy of cloud function with an exclamation mark. And if I delete that functions, then immediately a new function is deployed automatically. But instead of an exclamation mark, a spinning wheel symbol(loading/still deploying) mark is present. I cannot delete that cloud function if it is still loading/deploying. Then after 10-15 min, the spinning symbol changes to exclamation symbol. And then if I delete it, then again a new one automatically appears. And it goes on like this

Image 2 (Screenshot)
[Cloud Platform Cloud Function Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbvUf.png)

This problem arises only when implementing a webhook/fulfillment(Step 5). For static Actions' response, it successfully deploys for testing on entering the command "gactions deploy preview".(Step 1 to Step 4 are successfully implemented)

I have followed the tutorial as it is, hence the code and directory structure is the same as in tutorial,(only the project-id or actions-console project name will be different).

[Github Repository for Code](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-codelab-level-1)

Since, this is only for the tutorial, at present I am not using a billing account, instead did the following changes in package.json(changed node version from 10 to 8.).

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
},
```

Due to this continuous automatic failed deployment, when I try to explicitly deploy the project, as mentioned above, this error occurs.

```
 "An operation on function cf-_CcGD8lKs_F_LHmFYfJZsQ-name in region us-central1 in project <my-project-id> is already in progress. Please try again later".
```

Can anyone please suggest how to stop this continuous automatic failed deployment of the cloud functions, so that the function I deploy will be successfully deployed? Would really appreciate your help.

(Note: This is the first time I have posted a question in stack overflow, so please let me know if there are any mistakes or stack overflow question conventions I might not have followed. I will improve it.)

Comment: Did you "Associate a Billing Account" during the "Setup" step?

Comment: No, at present I am not using a billing account, I have changed the node version to '8' in package.json, which allows to use cloud functions without billing as of now. By changing the node to 8, before I was able to use cloud functions for simple webhooks.

Comment: Is the problem due to billing account? Because before, for another example I attempted, it worked fine without billing account.  The only difference was that then the webhook was written in typescript(index.ts) which worked and now its written in javascript(index.js) which doesnot work.

Comment: Hi @anonymous_D yes, the billing account can be causing the issue, as the tutorial mentions the indeed. While indeed Node.js 10 requires billing, this tutorial doesn't mention the need of Node.js version 10, but yes the billing account. Could you please associate one and check if it works? While it worked for your simple webhooks, it's not simple webhooks in the end of the tutorial.

Comment: IIRC, it's not possible to deploy Cloud Functions (webhooks) without a billing account. Also, when I created projects through Actions Console, I also had to manually enable the Cloud Build service before the deployment would succeed.

Comment: I have checked with billing account. It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as Community Wiki as it's based in the comments.

As clarified the issue seems to be the billing account, as the tutorial mentions that it's necessary to have one set for the Cloud Functions to be deployed correctly. Besides that, it's not possible to deploy Cloud Functions (webhooks) without a billing account, so yes, even though that you are not using Node.js 10, you will need to have a billing account configured for your project.

To summarize, billing account will be needed to avoid any possible deployment failure, even if you are not using Node.js 10, as explained in the followed [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-sdk-1#0).